# Emit light from items

Tags: xna, c#

In order to create a day/night cycle in my game, I decreased the r,g and b values of the Color variable after a certain amount of time has passed. This worked as expected. I am wondering in order to create light from an item, like a fire or lamp, could I create a circle around the item and set the color in that circle to be white? Or is there a better way for accomplishing this in 2d?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a post a mock-up screenshot that shows what kind of effect you want to achieve?

Comment: i tried my best lol

Comment: This seems like a "style" question... If this is a top-down 2d view (like your mockup) then a white circle to represent "lighted area" seems reasonable. I guess the key audience-experience of "light" is that you can see things "better" than in darkness. More details, or better colors, &c.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already, you should use a shader to make all the pixels on your screen darker for night.
You can draw a white circle (or a nice gradient circle) in a new render target at the appropriate position, then pass that render target as a Texture2D into the shader.
In the shader you can use the extra texture as a "mask" (or whatever you would like to call it).
The shader would make the pixels "less dark" where the mask has more alpha.
In this way you could even have multiple lighted objects -- just draw more than one mask into that render target.

If you do not know how to make shaders I highly recommend looking into that.
http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/shaders-in-xna

Otherwise, you could do one of these:

1) Draw a large texture centered around the light source. The texture would be all black, except for a hole in the center. You should not be able to see the edges of this texture. This may not work for what you are trying to accomplish though.

2) Loop through all the objects in the scene and make them darker if they are farther away from the light source. A hint:

```
float multiplier = 1.0f / (light.position - obj.position).Length();
```

Hope this helped!